# .htaccess PHP Router with HTTPS Redirect Not Working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site which runs on a very basic PHP router. All routes are redirected to a single PHP file which displays views based on the route. To make sure that all routes redirect to that PHP file, the following lines are included on my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /[routing PHP file here] [L,QSA]
```

I also would like users to automatically be redirected to the HTTPS version of a page if they go to that page with the HTTP protocol. I put the following lines before the lines for routing (I have tried both before and after) to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Routing works fine on HTTPS versions of the site. But when the HTTP version of a route is requested, the page just redirects to `https://[my site here]/[routing PHP file]` instead of `https://[my site here]/[correct route here]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The redirection to https must prepend the internal routing. Then all should work. If not then most likely you are looking at cached results. Please test again using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: @arkascha doesn't look like that worked — I tried on an incognito window and still experienced the same problems. I mentioned that I moved the HTTPS redirect to above the routing in the question: "I put the following lines **before** the lines for routing".